# How can I have one object create another object and insert a reference to itself in that second object?

Tags: java

I have an abstract class `Skill`, from which the actual skill classes inherit shared fields and methods. Then, the `Character` class creates new instances of each of these, like:

```
public class Character {
    String name;
    String className;
    String raceName;
    Acrobatics acrobatics = new Acrobatics();
    Diplomacy diplomacy = new Diplomacy();
    //etc.
}
```

So if you're not familiar with the d20 system, when you use a `Skill`, it checks against a difficulty class. Right now, the Skill classes themselves have a method to discover the DC (`discoverDC()`) for whatever check is being made.

The problem is that the `Skill` object has to check with the `Character` object that created it in order to discover all the relevant modifiers.

So to get it to work that way, I think I'd need to somehow attach a reference to the `Character` object that created the `Skill` object, but I have no idea how that would work. I've tried passing the `Character` object as a parameter to the `Skill` objects when they're created, but the compiler just gets irritated.

I'm pretty sure one solution would be to create another object that has these functions (like a GM) and have it look for relevant modifiers. However, I'd really like to know if there is any way to get this to work the way I originally put it together.

Comment: *I've tried passing the Character object as a parameter to the Skill objects when they're created, but the compiler just gets irritated* Instead of such a vague description, you should post *I have tried <this code>, but it produces <this compiler error>*. There's no way we can tell you why your code is wrong and how to fix it if you don't provide these details. *I'd really like to know if there is any way to get this to work the way I originally put it together*: we have no idea how you put it together, since you didn't post your code.

Comment: Compiler irritation usually suggests you're doing it wrong. Stop doing that. Doing what? How could we possibly know?

Comment: Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of the parent class to the child, so your child class needs an attribute for storing the object, then you can pass it with constructor or with a set method:

```
public class ParentClass{

    public void randomMethod(){
        ChildClass child = new ChildClass(this); 
    }


}
```

Here we have the child:

```
public class ChildClass{
    private ParentClass parent = null;

public ChildClass(ParentClass p){
    parent = new ParentClass();


   }
}
```

Comment: Oh my flippin gosh, thank you so much! I was trying to do exactly this thing except I didn't know to use the keyword `this`.